# WordPress: Make sidebar match height of main content area

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, height, sidebar

I'm taking an old WordPress site I designed years ago and now I'm making it responsive. Problem is I have a main content area on the site and a sidebar div and the issue is the sidebar div is not expanding down the entire height of the #contentWrap div on this site. I've already tried adding 100% heights to the #page, #contentWrap and #sidebar, all to no avail. On the old site design, I did a trick using background images, but that realistically won't work with a responsive desig.Any idea how I can make this work?

Site in question: http://destinationbeershow.com/episode-guide/

Code:

```
<div id="contentWrap">
<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contentWrap {
    width: 856px;
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
   background-color: #ac4f23;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 856px;
   height: 100%;
}

.narrowcolumn {
    background-color: #ac4f23;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 640px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#sidebar {
    padding: 16px 8px 10px 8px;
    float: right;
    width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    font: 11px 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ebd299;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make everything collapse below your 856px hard width and use percentages inside that, or you can fiddle with the math. You also don't mention how you are doing your media queries, I'm assuming mobile first, which means that IE8 won't see the columns unless you learn more about that or use desktop first responsive design, however to make the columns the same height no matter what is inside either, here's one way (display:table/display:table-cell) which stacks below the 856px width you have on your #page. Use percentages.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/biyito/1/

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.narrowcolumn {
    background-color: #ac4f23;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#sidebar {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ebd299;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width:856px) { 
    #contentWrap {
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
    .narrowcolumn {
        width: 80%;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    #sidebar {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 20%;
        border-left: 10px solid #fff;
        border-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentWrap">
  
   <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">
      <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
   </div>
  
   <div id="sidebar">
      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
   </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No, actually I'm using desktop first. This was originally all desktop so in order to get things done quickly on this site, I needed to go this route. I'm currently in the process of working on another site but will get to this later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

the #contentWrap has no height... i tried I really tried to make it responsive with your content but it just doesn't work. For now if you define the height of it, the bar will be end to end.

In that page the height would be 1361px

If you can place the content in http://jsfiddle.net/ is much more easy to find and get to the problem.

Comment: The problem with doing what you suggest means all pages would be at min-height or just height of 1361px. They're not all that height. Some are shorter and some are longer. I need something that will work on all pages.